# Laravel 5. Obtener todos los modelos con cierta relación

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Tengo esta estructura de base de datos:

1. gestion_menus (id, id_permiso, nombre);
2. permisos (id, codigo, nombre);
3. perfiles_permisos (id_permiso, id_perfil);
4. perfiles (id, nombre);
5. usuarios_perfiles (id_perfil, id_usuario);

Estas tablas tienen sus modelos definidos de la siguiente forma:

gestion_menus:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class GestionMenu extends Model {

    protected $table = "gestion_menus";

    public function permiso() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Permiso::class, 'id_permiso');
    }
}
```

permisos:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Zizaco\Entrust\EntrustPermission;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;

class Permiso extends EntrustPermission {

    public function roles() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Config::get('entrust.role'), Config::get('entrust.permission_role_table'), 'id_permiso', 'id_perfil');
    }

    public function menus() {
        return $this-hasMany(GestionMenu::class, 'id_permiso', 'id');
    }
}
```

perfiles:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Zizaco\Entrust\EntrustRole;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;

class Perfil extends EntrustRole {

    public function perms() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Config::get('entrust.permission'), Config::get('entrust.permission_role_table'), 'id_perfil', 'id_permiso');
    }
}
```

Necesito obtener una colección de los menús para los cuales un usuario dado tiene permiso.

He realizado multitud de pruebas y no lo he conseguido. Lo último que he intentado, por si sirve como base es lo siguiente:

```
GestionMenu::with(['permiso.roles' => function($query) {
            $query->whereIn('perfiles.id', Auth::user() ? Auth::user()->roles->pluck('id')->toArray() : [0]);
        }])->where([['activo', true], ['en_menu', true]]);
```

Con esto obtengo todos los items de gestion menú pero la relación con los perfiles viene vacía.

Answer (score 3):

Lo he resuelto de la siguiente forma:

```
GestionMenu::whereHas('permiso.roles', function($query) {
            $query->whereIn('perfiles.id', Auth::user() ? Auth::user()->roles->pluck('id')->toArray() : [0]);
        })->where([['activo', true], ['en_menu', true]]);
```

Comment: Por favor considera marcar tu respuesta como aceptada si la misma solucionó tu problema